# Jmeter File upload Scenario - Issue PUT with body

Tags: java, file, jmeter

I have a jmeter scenario where I need to upload a txt file of different size . To upload the file in jmeter , we enable multipart and request is of PUT type.

I am also getting put body , which is  creating issue in my log files in the backend . Posting a sample request body . Is there any way where we can just send data without any data showing up under put data .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot you're trying to upload a file to http://www.csm-testcenter.org/test page, the page assumes HTTP [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) method, not PUT.

If you're uncertain regarding proper JMeter configuration when it comes to uploading files be informed that you can just record the file upload event using your favourite browser (or another application) and JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder. All you need to do is to copy the file to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, this way JMeter will be able to properly capture the request and generate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)